# Mirror symmetry about the line $y = 1/x$

Tags: proof-explanation

This seems like a very simple computation, but I don't fully understand it.

Consider the line $y = 1/x$ in the first quadrant (i.e., when $x \geq 0$). We fix a point $x_0$ and consider the line tangent to $y = 1/x$ at the point $x_0$. Computationally, it's easier to see that the $y$-intercept is $2x_0$. The claim that I do not understand is that it should be true "by mirror symmetry" that the $x$-intercept immediately is $2y_0$. The argument the professor made is that
$$y = 1/x \iff xy = 1 \iff x = \frac{1}{y}.$$
I understand this, but we're looking at the tangent line, not at the original function $y$. I can observe the function and "see" that there may be some mirror symmetry, but I don't understand fully how the geometry works.

Comment: Perhaps she meant symmetry in the line $x=y$?

Comment: $y=1/x$ is not a line.

Comment: I should have been clearer. This is the $y$-intercept of the tangent line.

Comment: @user861776 I think you meant $2/x_{0}$ for the $y$-intercept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent at the point $(x_0,{1 \over x_0}) = ({1 \over y_0}, y_0)$ has the equation $y={1 \over x_0} -{1 \over x_0^2}(x-x_0)$, or, viewing it from the $y$ axis perspective
$x={1 \over y_0} -{1 \over y_0^2}(y-y_0)$.

It is clear that the equations are the same if we swap the symbol $x$ with $y$ (including the subscripted symbols), however
I would not call it mirror symmetry, more

Since the $y$ intercept is found by setting $x=0$ in the first equation (which gives  ${2 \over x_0})$, using the $x-y$ swap we see that the $x$ intercept is
${2 \over y_0}$.

Answer (score 1):

The original equation $y = (1/x)$ is a hyperbola.

This implies that $x = (1/y).$

This means that instead of regarding $y = f(x) = (1/x)$, you can regard $x = g(y) = (1/y).$

Then all of your analysis, namely that the slope is $\frac{-1}{x^2}$ and that $\frac{1}{x_0} + \frac{x_0}{(x_0)^2} = \frac{2}{x_0}$ will be **perfectly paralleled** when you consider $x = g(y) = (1/y)$.